# How can I derive the following integral inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

Let $A=\{u\in C^1[0,1]:u(0)=u(1)=0\}$ and $B=\{u\in C^1[0,1]:u(0)=0\}$. Show that for all $u\in B$,

$\int_0^12u^2 dx\le\int_0^1u'^2 dx$

and for all $u\in A$

$\int_0^14u^2 dx\le\int_0^1u'^2 dx$.

Is this approach correct?

The first inequality holds for polynomials $x^np(x)$. So by uniform convergence and Weierstrass approximation theorem, the inequality holds for all $u\in B$.
The second inequality holds for polynomials $x^n(x-1)^mp(x)$. So by uniform convergence and Weierstrass approximation theorem, the inequality holds for all $u\in A$.

Comment: How do you conclude that the inequality holds for all $u\in B$? If you have a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly to $u$, then the sequence of the derivatives may not converge, so $\int_0^1 u'^2 dx$ may not be the limit of the integrals over the derivatives.

Comment: Alternatively you could use $u(x)=\int_0^x u'(t)dt$ and Cauchy-Schwarz for the first part.